# bitwise OR in linux open flags

Tags: c, linux

In the linux `open` system call, what is the meaning of bitwise OR in flags. How this is interpreted by the compiler. Here's an example:

```
fd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR);
```

Also, what does comma operator do in flags?

**Update:** What is the effect of using other operators like if we do `&&` operator

Comment: That's not a comma operator - it's a comma that separates the flags argument from the mode argument.

Comment: And your question is answered in detail here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: I saw in man pages, that it combines all flags. But I don't understand how? Because if it combines then it produce a int value, so how does compiler understand

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How this is interpreted by the compiler

Not differently than any other bitwise OR operation. Consider the following `#define`s as found for example in `/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h` (note that values are in octal):

```
#define O_RDONLY        00000000
#define O_CREAT         00000100
#define O_TRUNC         00001000
```

Then, in your example, the value passed to the function is `00000000 | 00000100 | 00001000` which is **`00001100`**. By evaluating the various bit positions, `open()` can reconstruct which of the flags had been set by the caller:

```
if (oflag & O_CREAT) {
   /* caller wants the file to be created */
}

if (oflag & O_TRUNC) {
   /* caller wants the file to be truncated */
}
...
```

Comment: Interesting how you don't need to specify `O_RDONLY`...

Answer (score 3):

This is the prototype of the function:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

This is the way you are calling it:

```
fd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR);
```

So you are passing the following arguments:

- `pathname = "myfile"`
- `flags    = O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`
- `mode     = S_IRUSR` (user has read permission)

The argument `flags` must include **exactly one** of the following access modes: `O_RDONLY` or `O_WRONLY` or `O_RDWR`. These requests will open the file read-only or write-only or read/write, respectively.

When combined with `O_CREAT`, if the file does not exist then it will be created.

When combined with `O_TRUNC`, if the file already exists and is a regular file and the open mode allows writing (i.e., is `O_RDWR` or `O_WRONLY`) then it will be truncated to length 0.

Please note that the (undefined) effect of `O_RDONLY | O_TRUNC` varies among implementations. On many systems the file is actually truncated.

**Update:**

These flags are typically meant to be used only with the bit-wise OR operator (`|`).

If you want to use all possible flags except for a few, then you can use the bit-wise FLIP operator (`~`). For example: `~(O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC)`... but don't try this one in specific at home...

It is pretty pointless to use any other bit-wise operator in this case, and it is most certainly pointless to use any other **non-bit-wise operator**, such as logical AND (`&&`).

Answer (score 2):

The bitwise OR is applying a logical OR to the specified values. The flags are defined as a bitmask or individual bits, and with the OR operation you can set the specified bits in the target, without changing other bits.

```
A: 1 1 0 0
B: 1 0 1 0
-----------
 = 1 1 1 0
```

So what happens in this call is that all the flags that you specified are set in the resulting value and passed to the function

```
#define _O_RDONLY       0    <- Bit 0
#define _O_WRONLY       1    <- Bit 0
#define _O_RDWR         2    <- Bit 1

#define _O_CREAT    0x0100  /* Create the file if it does not exist. */
#define _O_TRUNC    0x0200  /* Truncate the file if it does exist. */

O_RDONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC = 0x0000 + 0x0100 + 0x0200 = 0x0300

0000 0000 0000 0000 O_RDONLY
0000 0001 0000 0000 O_CREAT
0000 0010 0000 0000 O_TRUNC
---------------------------
0000 0011 0000 0000 = 0x0300
```

So the compiler passes 0x0300 to the open call.

As to your second question:

The `open` call is defined as `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);`

So the comma is simply separating the individual arguments and is not part of the flags. Just like in any other function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Also, what does comma operator do in flags?
```

It is the third argument mode to the `open` call.

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

**what is the meaning of bitwise OR in flags**

```
#define O_RDONLY             00
#define O_CREAT            0100 
#define O_TRUNC           01000
```

A combination of these macros would set different bits, in the flags variable, based on which the open call proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

open function call takes 1 argument as file path and second argument for flags,

arguments are comma seperated,

BITWISE OR on flags enables the corresponding bits of that number accordingly.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Answer (score 0):

The flags `O_RDONLY`, `O_CREAT` are just numbers having a particular bit as `1`. So you can say that their values are in power of `2`. I dont know their exact value but let me give you example of permissions.

There are three settings for permission `READ`, `WRITE` and `EXECUTE`. Read has value `4` , `100` in binary.   Similarly `WRITE` has value `2`, `010` in binary and `EXECUTE` has value `1`, `001` in binary.

When you want to set a particular setting, you `OR` it with zero, so that particular bit becomes `1`.   So i<sup>th</sup> bit is reserved for only one particular setting. The function just find which bits are set and works according to that.

If `READ` and `WRITE` are set, it means `100` | `010` = `110`, 6 in decimal
If all settings are give, it means 111, i.e. 7 in decimal.

Hence difference flag values corresponds to different combinations of settings.